# Can Global Accelerator or Load balancer route traffic to APIs on AWS API Gateway where APIs have backend micro services outside of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-global-accelerator

Can Global Accelerator or Load balancer route traffic  to  APIs on AWS API Gateway where APIs  have backend micro services outside of AWS?   My clients are coming from internet, they need to call various APIs deployed on AWS Apigateway where the backend micro services mostly outside of my AWS account, they are  either on another AWS account and most of then on NON AWS infra.

My job is to build APIs on AWS Gateway and have them exposed to external partners.  I don't own micro services.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but you will simply not profit as much as you would maybe expect since the call from the api gateway to the actual service will not be completely routed within AWS network but (at least) partially through the open internet. And at that point I would we asking myself why you do all the work in and out of AWS, what is the benefit?

Comment: Thanks for your response.   Here is the  reason why I need to do work in and out of AWS - I have an APIGW which exposes APIs to external partners, backend micro services are on perm VSI.  I need to move  APIGW into AWS , but the backend micro services won't be on AWS for an year or 18months, Goal is to move APIGW to AWS and have partners connect to APIs on AWS , while I can migrate my backend services one by one.